# Cannot Debug C++ in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, c++

I want to debug my C++ code in VSCode, but after I pressed `F5`, the external console didn't pop up as expected.

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "E:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile for Debug"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile for Debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wl,--stack=1024000000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I press `F5`, the window looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkonK.png)

It seems that the debug session runs normally (the bar in the red box), but as you can see, the external console doesn't appear.

P.S. My system is Windows 10 (x64), and the vscode is the latest.

Comment: Did you wait long enough? `gdb` might need some time to start, and I see a loading bar in the top-left corner.

Comment: Yes of course. I waited for almost 5 minutes but nothing happened, and that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Huh. Does `gdb` work if you start it from the terminal?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I know how to solve that. It seems a bug of C/C++ extension.

I just set the option "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Windows OFF, and everything works.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4140).
Thanks a lot to Github user @everything411.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell looking at your picture, is that I the program stopped at your break point (I don't use the same version so I'm not entirely sure). You have to click next for your program to finish compiling. If you just want to see what your output is, no break points or anything, hit Crtl + F5.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to learn how to use C++ debugger in **Linux**:

[VS Code Debugger for C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

This tutorial is the official tutorial by the *Microsoft VS Code Community*.

Follow the steps and you will get to know how to debug C++ files.

> **Note**: You need to have a project folder and keep you `.cpp` inside it.